# content jumps when scrollbar is added on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

In all of my `div`s, I am adding `scrollbar` on hover if necessary. Initially the overflow is set to `hidden` for that `div` and on hover it becomes `auto`.

```
div{
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
div:hover{
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

but when the scrollbar is added on hover, the content jumps to the left. I don't want to make the scrollbar present all the time, I only want to add it when we hover over the div and there is overflow in that div.

Comment: For this you can use custom scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine

```css
div{
 height:100px;
 border:1px solid black;
 overflow:hidden;
 width:183px;
 }
 
 div:hover{
 overflow:auto;
 width:200px;
 }
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ornare bibendum varius. In tempor et neque a luctus. Integer vel diam sed sapien lacinia tincidunt. Sed lobortis rhoncus velit, at molestie sem varius id. Sed vel leo in neque sollicitudin lacinia. Mauris a ultrices enim. Aliquam sollicitudin tempor neque, vitae varius felis lobortis ac. Vestibulum et ultrices augue. Proin eros magna, dapibus et orci sit amet, tempus imperdiet risus. Etiam ac nisi in mi aliquet blandit. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis iaculis neque justo, quis commodo magna pharetra ut.
</div>
```

**EDIT**
Just add >17px width on hover, it will work

Comment: check it, its also shifting the text to left.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have used [perfect-scrollbar](https://utatti.github.io/perfect-scrollbar/).

```js
$('.perfectscroll').perfectScrollbar();
```

```css
div.perfectscroll{
   height:100px;
   border:1px solid black;
   overflow:hidden;
   width:50%;
   position:relative;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.perfect-scrollbar/0.6.10/css/perfect-scrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.perfect-scrollbar/0.6.10/js/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.js"></script>

<div class="perfectscroll">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ornare bibendum varius. In tempor et neque a luctus. Integer vel diam sed sapien lacinia tincidunt. Sed lobortis rhoncus velit, at molestie sem varius id. Sed vel leo in neque sollicitudin lacinia. Mauris a ultrices enim. Aliquam sollicitudin tempor neque, vitae varius felis lobortis ac. Vestibulum et ultrices augue. Proin eros magna, dapibus et orci sit amet, tempus imperdiet risus. Etiam ac nisi in mi aliquet blandit. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis iaculis neque justo, quis commodo magna pharetra ut.
</div>
```

Comment: this works but it starts the scrollbar at the wrong position. Unable to position it using css.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this post](https://codepen.io/sambible/post/browser-scrollbar-widths) where scrollbars are usually 17px wide, you can set the div to be 17px thinner, allowing room for the scrollbar to appear once you hover over, and still maintain the width of the `div`.

```
div{
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: calc(100% - 17px)
}
div:hover{
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%
}
```

With example:

```css
div{
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: calc(50% - 17px);
}

div:hover {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 50%
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus ornare bibendum varius. In tempor et neque a luctus. Integer vel diam sed sapien lacinia tincidunt. Sed lobortis rhoncus velit, at molestie sem varius id. Sed vel leo in neque sollicitudin lacinia. Mauris a ultrices enim. Aliquam sollicitudin tempor neque, vitae varius felis lobortis ac. Vestibulum et ultrices augue. Proin eros magna, dapibus et orci sit amet, tempus imperdiet risus. Etiam ac nisi in mi aliquet blandit. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis iaculis neque justo, quis commodo magna pharetra ut.
</div>
```